# What role title/level should I put on my resume?

Tags: software-industry, software-development

I have a few years of experience as a software developer in different companies around the globe. Most of the companies were start-ups or software development wasn't their main business. I've started looking for a new job recently and while updating my resume I was wondering what level of experience should I put for different roles.

In the most cases, I was employed just as a software/web developer, but in the end, I had to deal with the wide range tasks: managing databases and clouds, designing the whole IT systems from scratch, coding everything, etc.

Pretty much in all companies, I was the only developer, therefore I needed to convert employer's ideas to the working code (or whole IT system) from scratch. It even happened in my first job when I was just an intern.

Should I call myself senior developer, if I have just a couple of years of experience? Should I state roles in my resume as `Software Developer, DevOps Engineer, System Architect` for every company or just *official titles*?

Comment: @DavidK my question is more about “measuring” my level of expertise, but thanks for the link!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere 2 companies don’t exist anymore, in the rest of the companies hr/admin staff would reference me as “developer” or “IT staff”, without any specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best term I would use for this type of end-to-end work would be "Full Stack Engineer".

I wouldn't use SRE or DevOps Engineer, because they tend to include an on-call component that you didn't mention. Software Architect seems like you design a system and hand it off to someone else to implement.

Answer (score 5):

Put your official titles. What you actually done for the employer you can describe in the job description/duties/accomplishments section.

Keep in mind that if somebody is going to be verifying your employment they would contact HR Departments of your previous employer(s) who might have no idea on what were you projects or might not even know you at all. And if somebody is going to have "Application Architect" on the resume but previous employer would state that title was "Web Developer" then there might be a problem.